# Функция lazyLoad у Slick-slidera

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, slick.js, lazyloading

Подскажите пожалуйста как работает функция Lazy load у [slick slider-a](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) она ведь должна работать так - При загрузке страницы у слайдера загружается ровно столько слайдов сколько у него установлено, а при прокрутке они должны как бы подгружаться дополнительно. Или это работает только когда элементами слайда являются изображения а не блок который содержит и текст и изображения.

Вот это хотелось бы понять.

Answer (score 1):

В стандартном состоянии слайдер осуществляет резкую замену слайдов. Но функционал Slick предусматривает плавный режим замены слайдов. Для этого нужно прибегнуть к атрибуту data-lazy, в котором прописывается путь к картинке. Атрибут нужно присвоить не обертке, а именно тегу изображения. Это позволит избежать использование js-кода. Альтернативой будет эта команда: lazyLoad: 'ondemand'

Атрибут следует записывать так:

```
<img data-lazy =" images/slaid.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

При инициализации будет загружено то что в src
а при показе то что в data-lazy, так будет выглядеть красивее особенного когда подргужаемая картинка большая или например сеть потеряна.

```
<img data-lazy="images/slaid_max.jpg" src="images/slaid_min.jpg">
```